# Auto Display Data from database and show it on LCD screen

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

I want to create something like the following using php and mysql :-

http://prositos.no/cl/

It is the same or simillar to :-

- Flight Information System
- Movie Showtime listing at cinemas

Is it possible? I don't know is the exact name for this auto changing page. I tried to search on net for tutorial but no luck.

Can someone please help/guide me in getting some idea on how to start.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What problem, directly related to programming did you encounter?

Comment: We can not provide personal tutoring here, please do a minimum research your own, if you are getting into concrete programming problems, you then can ask. You might be looking for Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get flight data from any site that provides an API you can use (or parse a site that has the data you need)
2. Save the data to your database
3. Create a site that displays the cached flight data

Whenever someone opens your site you have to check how old the cached data is. If it is (for example 1 minute) too old you would get renew the flight data before outputting the site.

Another way would be to setup a cronjob that renews the cached flight data every n minutes.

You can add some javascript to let the page reload itself via AJAX every n minutes.

Comment: I am not going to create a flight information system. I just want to create something like that for my students to check on their daily class schedule. I want to display this in LCD located in the student lounge. So that my students can check their classes. 

For that, i plan to develop it. I plan to use php and the data are stored in mysql. How can i call this data...and show in table form? i want to use pagination to limit the number of record and the ajax is used to auto navigate the page and loop. how can i go about it?

Thanks.

Comment: I am sorry, but as hakre already stated in the comments this is a question & answer platform. If you have specific questions you can find answers here. Its expected that you at least learned/know the basics (there are tons of php and sql tutorials out there).